# Cannot resolve symbol 'listener'

Tags: java, android, button, listener, calculator

I have the following error "Cannot resolve symbol 'listener'" in my following code but can't seem to get rid of this. Any ideas of why this error would appear?

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Spinner spr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        EditText editText6 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        TextView textView8 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        String selectedItem =(String) spr.getSelectedItem();
        int intItemPosition =spr.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if (selectedItem.trim().equals("*")){
            float result = Float.parseFloat(editText6.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(Integer.toString(planlist.get(intItemPosition).getCalories()));
            textView8.setText(Float.toString(result));
        }

        Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }
```

Comment: it means that `listener` is not defined anywhere (`button4.setOnClickListener(listener);` )

Comment: Please show the full class. In this snippet listener is not defined

Comment: where you have created `listener` object?

Comment: Oops, had an error with my listener. I have sorted this now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listener needs to be declared:

```
private planOnClickListener myClickListener = new planOnClickListener();
```

And appropriate link to the listener:

```
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```